# Receiving "HTTP ERROR 401 " on IIS server

Tags: iis

After having installed IIS on my computer and then later removed it after a few months, I am currently in the process of configuring it again. However, when I try to access localhost in my browser, I receive an error message.

> HTTP ERROR 401

[Pool Identity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Snyq.png)

Despite checking the pool identity authentication and not finding any issues there, as well as restarting my computer, I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Please post detailed error messages, need more error messages to troubleshoot your issue, if not, you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error information.